# Cut specified number of rows in selected range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem, 
I have e.g 180 rows in sheet, I want to choose randomly e.g 18 rows in range from A2 to the end of sheet except first because there will be title of columns,  and paste it to new sheet,

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will achieve what you are wanting, it will generate 18 random numbers between 2 and your last row with data, in your case row 180 and then copy that row into the next free row in Sheet2:

```
Sub foo()
Dim wsOriginal As Worksheet: Set wsOriginal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet: Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
'declare and set the worksheets you are working with, amend as required
Dim i As Long, LastRowOrig As Long, LastRowDest As Long

LastRowOrig = wsOriginal.Cells(wsOriginal.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A on your Sheet with data

For i = 1 To 18 'loop 18 times
    RandNumber = Int((LastRowOrig - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
    'generate a random number between 2 and 180 (Last Row)
    LastRowDest = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'get the last row with data on Destination sheet and offset by one (i.e. next free row)
    wsOriginal.Rows(RandNumber).Copy 'copy the row
    wsDestination.Rows(LastRowDest).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'paste the row
Next i
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

To reflect your comment and add a new workbook with the random rows in it, use the following code:

```
Sub foo()
Dim wsOriginal As Worksheet: Set wsOriginal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, LastRowOrig As Long, LastRowDest As Long

Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add 'create a new workbook
    With NewWorkbook
        .Title = "Random Rows" 'You can modify this value.
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\doneby\Desktop\RandomGeneratedRows.xlsx"
        'amend the line above to the path you and name of the file you want to create
    End With
Set wsDestination = NewWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'specify the Sheet of the new workbook
'declare and set the worksheets you are working with, amend as required

LastRowOrig = wsOriginal.Cells(wsOriginal.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A on your Sheet with data

For i = 1 To 18 'loop 18 times
    RandNumber = Int((LastRowOrig - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
    'generate a random number between 2 and 180 (Last Row)
    LastRowDest = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'get the last row with data on Destination sheet and offset by one (i.e. next free row)
    wsOriginal.Rows(RandNumber).Copy 'copy the row
    wsDestination.Rows(LastRowDest).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'paste the row
Next i
NewWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
'close and save the new workbook
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thank you ! It works perfectly but, I need one update , can i change wsOrginal name "Sheet1" because i want to make this in active workbook and "Sheet2" change to open new and input data there

Comment: @doneby I've now updated my answer to reflect your comment and create a new workbook and save it with the random rows. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: it works perfectly but i'be made mistake i didn't mean new excel file but new sheet in the same where i launch the macro what should I change , It helps a lot ofc !

Comment: Hi , I need one more update because, It creates new new excel file and my worksheet need to be named "Sheet1" but I want to operate in active worksheet and cut rows to new worksheet , everything in one file ,